# is there a way other than read/echo to read one line from a file descriptor to stdout without closing the fd?

Tags: bash, pipeline, file-descriptor

I ran into a situation where I was doing:

```
outputStuff |
filterStuff |
transformStuff |
doMoreStuff |
endStuff > endFile
```

I want to be able to insert some debug tracing stuff in a fashion like:

```
tee debugFile.$((debugNum++)) |
```

but obviously the pipes create subshells, so I wanted to do this instead.

```
exec 5< <(seq 1 100)
outputStuff |
tee debugFile.$(read -u 5;echo $REPLY;) |
filterStuff |
tee debugFile.$(read -u 5;echo $REPLY;) |
transformStuff |
tee debugFile.$(read -u 5;echo $REPLY;) |
doMoreStuff |
endStuff > endFile
```

ie, I want the debug line I insert to be identical, so I don't have to worry about stepping on various stuff.  The read/REPLY echo seems really ugly.. I suppose I could wrap in a function.. but *is there a way to read one line from a file descriptor to stdout without closing the fd* (like a head -1 would close the fd is I did head -1 <&3)

Comment: I'd consider this by building the pipeline with a recursive function -- that way you get guaranteed ordering without needing to mess with `seq` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several things, but in the end @Etan Reisner proved to me (unintentionally) that even if there is a way to do what you asked (clever, Etan), it's not what you actually want.  If you want to be sure to read the numbers back sequentially then the reads have to be serialized, which the commands in a pipeline are not.

Indeed, that applies to your original approach as well, since command substitutions are performed in subshells.  I think you could reliably do it like this, though:

```
debugum=1
eval "
    outputStuff |
    tee debugFile.$((debugNum++)) |
    filterStuff |
    transformStuff |
    doMoreStuff |
    tee debugFile.$((debugNum++)) |
    endStuff > endFile
"
```

That way all the substitutions are performed by the parent shell, on the string, before any of the commands is launched.

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't even thought of those commands not being required to be started in order, but I do think that's not guaranteed, as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Put all the reads inside a single compound statement, and redirect input from descriptor 5 for *that*.

```
{ outputStuff    | tee debugFile.$(read -u 5;echo $REPLY;) |
  filterStuff    | tee debugFile.$(read -u 5;echo $REPLY;) |
  transformStuff | tee debugFile.$(read -u 5;echo $REPLY;) |
  doMoreStuff    |
  endStuff
} 5< <(seq 1 100) > endFile
```

Now, file descriptor 5 is opened once (and closed once), and each call to `read` gets successive lines from that descriptor.

(You can also simplify this a bit; unless you are providing `outputStuff` with input via the keyboard, there doesn't seem to be a need to use file descriptor 5 instead of standard input, since only `outputStuff` is reading from standard input. All the other programs are reading their standard input via the pipeline.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that doesn't need `seq` at all:

Define a function that constructs your pipeline recursively.

```
buildWithDebugging() {
  local -a nextCmd=( )
  local debugNum=$1; shift
  while (( $# )) && [[ $1 != '|' ]]; do
    nextCmd+=( "$1" )
    shift
  done
  if (( ${#nextCmd[@]} )); then
    "${nextCmd[@]}" \
      | tee "debugFile.$debugNum" \
      | buildWithDebugging "$((debugNum + 1))" "$@"
  else
    cat # noop
  fi
}
```

...and, to use it:

```
buildWithDebugging 0 \
  outputStuff '|'
  filterStuff '|'
  transformStuff '|'
  doMoreStuff '|'
  endStuff > endFile
```

A more secure version would use pipeline components done in the style of Pascal strings rather than C strings -- which is to say, instead of using literal `|`s, preceding each string of commands with its length:

```
buildWithDebugging 0 \
  1 outputStuff
  3 filterStuff filterArg filterSecondArg
  2 transformStuff filterArg
  1 doMoreStuff
  endStuff > endFile
```

Building this should be a completely trivial exercise for the reader. :)

Answer (score 0):

At the cost of evenly padding your numbers you can do this with dd though you don't end up with a nicer looking command for your trouble. =)

```
exec 5< <(seq -w 10 -1 1)
echo -n |
{ echo "d 1:$(dd bs=1 count=3 2>/dev/null <&5)"; cat; } |
{ echo "d 2:$(dd bs=1 count=3 2>/dev/null <&5)"; cat; } |
{ echo "d 3:$(dd bs=1 count=3 2>/dev/null <&5)"; cat; } |
{ echo "d 4:$(dd bs=1 count=3 2>/dev/null <&5)"; cat; } |
cat
```

You can also just use a shorter variable with `read`: `read -u 5 a;echo $a` but that only saves you two characters.

Comment: That's not reliably giving me the numbers in order, which makes sense because you multiple different processes reading from the same file descriptor produces a race.  Most often the first process in the pipeline is the first to read, etc., but that's not guaranteed.

Comment: That reliably gave me the output in reverse order but I suppose it might not be guaranteed to do that. And having real process work involved probably isn't going to help its reliability. That being said this is just uglier than your `read` solution anyway.