Equivalent for pipe() in bash or other shell
In libc, there is an ability to create an (anonymous) pipe:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html
I am aware of mkfifo in bash and similar shells, and I am aware of the | which allows anonymous piping between the stdout of one process to another's stdin. As per an answer given, also of process substitution. But these are not quite the same functionality as pipe(), which provides a file descriptor for each end of a pipe to be used later or passed on to other processes.
I wondered if there was a trivial equivalent of pipe of which I am unaware?

Bash coprocesses may do what you want.  See How do you use the command coproc in various shells?.

Maybe you'd be interested in exec redirections, as can have up to 9 in most shells and using {nn} notation, even more. The best I could find here was https://stackoverflow.com/q/25535036/620097 , but the key to searching effectively was [bash] exec "1>&3" -find -(other annoying keywords) . Good luck.

There is no equivalent to pipe() in shell.
The closest POSIX and typically used is mktemp with mkfifo.
In Bash you can do coproc cat and use ${COPROC[0]} and ${COPROC[1]} as a pipe descriptors. Note that you can only run one coproc at a time.
You can also write a bash builtin that will call a pipe() and set two Bash variables.

I am marking this as correct as this is the conclusion that I have reached given the answers which have arrived so far.

You can create an anonymous pipe using process substitution
For example, this will loop over all .sh files under the current directory:
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
    : # do stuff

done < <(find . -name '*.sh' -print0)

An other example: send all output to a logger

loggerForStdout()
{
    echo "loggerForStdout started"

    local x  # only in this block
    while IFS= read -r x
    do
        printf "%(%T)T - loggerForStdout - '%s'\n" -1 "${x}"
    done

    echo "loggerForStdout ended"
}

exec > >(loggerForStdout)

echo "TEST" # this will display "<date> - loggerForStdout - 'TEST'"


This is a good answer, but doesn't really do the same thing as pipe() - which provides an pair of file descriptors (one read, one write) for later use. e.g. passing them into the program.
I will adjust my question to make that easier to identify as a concern.

@philip-adler you're right I missed that! You could try bash coproc. I will not give you any example since do not know much more than it exists

That is definitely interesting and does allow one to do something very similar in the context of running another process.
